# Transform: translateX breaks text selection in inputs in Chrome

Tags: css

TranslateX breaks text selection in Inputs in Chrome.

```
div {
  background: #afe5a4;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  transform:translateX(150px);
}

input {
  width: 100%;  
}
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/k42g91h1/1/

Try to select text in input and move cursor outside the green box to the left.
You will see how strange text is selected.

How to fix that?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use translate for this? Can't you do it with margin or something?

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird bug. I don't know how and why you are using `translateX` but you could basically trick the browser to think that the input is where it actually is by giving the input a negative `translateX` of the same value your div has and setting margin accordingly.

```
input {
  width: 100%; 
  transform:translateX(-150px);
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/72zx4tw0/

Comment: Thanks for reply! Already found this solution, but we set translateX by js with animation and we have too many inputs with different position. Hoped there is a better solution.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Well at least right now I can not figure out anything else...I'll get back to you if I do

Answer (score 0):

Exist chromium bug:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=928659&q=transform%20translate%20input&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Fow workaround you can use

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pm9L1g4u/